# Strange javascript behavior of `map` in Firefox

Tags: javascript

Here's some strange javascript behavior of the `map` function in Firefox.

During an error condition of a web-app (when firebug pauses on the error) typing the following into Firebug console:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"].map(function(val, i, arr) {
    return val + " " + i + " " + typeof arr;
});
```

produces the following un-expected result:

```
["a undefined undefined",
"b undefined undefined", 
"c undefined undefined", 
"d undefined undefined"]
```

At that time, if I open up another blank tab and type the same statement into the blank tab's Firebug Console, it produces the following expected result:

```
["a 0 object", 
"b 1 object", 
"c 2 object", 
"d 3 object"]
```

This means, in the error condition, `map` calls the callback with 1 argument instead of the expected 3 arguments.

Quote from MDN:
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> callback is invoked with three arguments: the value of the element,
>   the index of the element, and the Array object being traversed.

Is the unexpected behavior because of the app forcing firefox into some mode?

(I'm using Firefox 12.0)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6WRqp/ --- FF12, cannot reproduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like some other code in your application might be overwriting the Array.prototype.map function -- an incompletely implemented polyfill, perhaps? If you type `[].map` into the console, and if it doesn't say `function map() { [native code] }` then this is almost certainly the case.

Comment: Yes... that's happens.  Typing `[].map` in the error condition says `function()` while in the good condition, `[].map` says `map()`.

Comment: As soon as I saw your answer, I remember reading about it but it didn't strike me. Makes sense as I just included a 3rd party library. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> ["a", "b", "c", "d"].map(function(val, i, arr) { return val + " " + i + " " + typeof arr; });
["a 0 object", "b 1 object", "c 2 object", "d 3 object"]
```

Firefox 12. Sounds like you have some JS library that creates its own `Array.prototype.map`.

You can easily check this using firebug:

```
>>> Array.prototype.map.toString()
"function map() { [native code] }"
```

If you do not get the `[native code]` function you are overwriting the function with something else.

Comment: `Array.prototype.map.toString()` shows the function which overwrote the map method.  I just included an external library and thats whats causing it. Thanks you!